# What's the difference between "hard" and "crushing" difficulty?

Tags: uncharted-3

While watching videos of "Crushing" difficulty on Uncharted 3, (see my answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42436/what-is-the-trick-to-the-final-boss-fight-in-uncharted-3), although beware of spoilers) I noticed that it seemed like there were no button prompts during the QuickTime Events.  I've never played an Uncharted game on Crushing.   I expected it to take less hits to kill Nathan, but is this lack of QTE prompts also a feature of Crushing difficulty?  Are there any other differences between "hard" and "crushing?"

Comment: One of them hurts when you collide with it, and the other is actively trying to murder you.

Comment: You should totally give Crushing a go. You get a real sense of achievement when finishing the game on Crushing difficulty. The trick is to be a lot less reckless than you'd normally be, and make judicious use of cover. Also, prepare to be patient, as you will die. A lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increased enemy health and accuracy, decreased health for Drake (or at least he takes a lot more damage!) are the main differences. I don't think spawn rates are affected but they may be.

Treasures, puzzles and general proceedings in the game remain the same, and I'm pretty sure the QTEs are still there (no source though - haven't played it on Crushing myself yet)

Comment: You are mostly correct, but a lot of the QTEs are no longer there. For example, the QTE prompts for the new melee combat in Uncharted 3 no longer shows in Crushing. Some QTE prompts still remain though, such as ones used to finish off some boss battles.

Comment: Another difference in Uncharted 1 was that cheats were disabled in crushing. Is this also the cas in Uncharted 3?

Answer (score 0):

It's a major jump from hard for players looking for a real challenge and a test of patience. Uncharted 2's crushing wasn't to bad, but Uncharted 1 had sections that were pretty crazy and you have to really think about what weapons to keep on you and take forward etc.